# Merge csv files by adding the values in same column entries when present

Tags: csv, merge, addition

I have a number of csv files. Two example files are shown below.

input1.csv

```
Actinocyclus actinochilus,7
Asterionella formosa,4
Aulacodiscus orientalis,1
Aulacoseira granulata,3
Chaetoceros radicans,1
Corethron hystrix,6
Coscinodiscaceae 1 
Dactyliosolen fragilissimus,32
Diadesmis gallica,1
Diatoma hyemalis 1
Synedropsis hyperboreoides,4
Trigonium formosum,4
Urosolenia eriensis,2
```

input2.csv

```
Actinocyclus actinochilus,55
Asterionella formosa,3
Aulacoseira granulata,5
Chaetoceros radicans,7
Dactyliosolen fragilissimus,5
Diatoma hyemalis,1
Stephanopyxis turris,1
Striatella unipunctata,1
Synedropsis hyperboreoides,28
Trigonium formosum,3
Urosolenia eriensis,2
```

I want to merge these csv files by adding column two based on the same name in column one as in the example output below.

output.csv

```
Actinocyclus actinochilus,62
Asterionella formosa,7
Aulacodiscus orientalis,1
Aulacoseira granulata,8
Chaetoceros radicans,8
Corethron hystrix,6
Coscinodiscaceae, 1 
Dactyliosolen fragilissimus,37
Diadesmis gallica,1
Diatoma hyemalis,2
Stephanopyxis turris,1
Striatella unipunctata,1
Synedropsis hyperboreoides,32
Trigonium formosum,7
Urosolenia eriensis,4
```

I tried join and cat but these stacked them together. Any idea how could add them together?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried join and cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution for multiple files

**This is a Python 3 solution. If you need it to work with Python 2, change this line `names = inp.keys() | data.keys()`  into `names = inp.viewkeys() | data.viewkeys()`.**

```
# get this list of file names form somewhere like `glob`
file_names = ['input1.csv', 'input2.csv', 'input3.csv', 'input4.csv']

def file_to_dict(file_name):
    """Read a two-column csv file into a dict with first column as key
       and an integer value from the second column. 
    """
    with open(file_name) as fobj:
        pairs = (line.split(',') for line in fobj if line.strip())
        return {k.strip(): int(v) for k, v in pairs}

def merge(data, file_name):
    """Merge input file with dict `data` adding the numerical values.
    """
    inp = file_to_dict(file_name)
    names = inp.keys() | data.keys()
    for name in names:
        data[name] = data.get(name, 0) + inp.get(name, 0)
    return data

data = {}
for file_name in file_names:
    merge(data, file_name)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fobj:
    for name, val in sorted(data.items()):
        fobj.write('{},{}\n'.format(name, val))
```

### Solution for two files

This produces the desired output:

```
def file_to_dict(file_name):
    """Read a two-column csv file into a dict with first column as key
       and an integer value from the second column. 
    """
    with open(file_name) as fobj:
        pairs = (line.split(',') for line in fobj if line.strip())
        return {k.strip(): int(v) for k, v in pairs}

inp1 = file_to_dict('input1.csv')
inp2 = file_to_dict('input2.csv')
names = sorted(inp1.keys() | inp2.keys())

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fobj:
    for name in names:
        val = inp1.get(name, 0) + inp2.get(name, 0)
        fobj.write('{},{}\n'.format(name, val))
```

### Explanation

The function `file_to_dict` reads one input file and returns a dictionary like this:

```
{'Actinocyclus actinochilus': 7,
 'Asterionella formosa': 4,
  ...
```

Next:

```
pairs = (line.split(',') for line in fobj if line.strip())
```

`pairs` holds a generator expression that represents all name-value pairs as strings. Then:

```
{k.strip(): int(v) for k, v in pairs}
```

creates a dictionary from this pairs, stripping of extra whits space from the name and converting the string in the second column into an integer.

After reading both input files with this function:

```
names = sorted(inp1.keys() | inp2.keys())
```

uses the union of the names from both inputs, i.e. all names that appear in input1 and input2 and sorts them alphabetically.

The output file needs to be open in write mode:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as fobj:
```

for each name:

```
    for name in names:
```

we retrieve the value from the input dictionaries:

```
val = inp1.get(name, 0) + inp2.get(name, 0)
```

The method `get` returns the value if the name is in the dictionary. Otherwise, it returns the `0` given as second argument.

Finally, we write this result line by line:

```
fobj.write('{},{}\n'.format(name, val))
```

Comment: No, as I have 6 to 9 files I have to merge

Comment: @user3767953 Added a version for multiple files.